# How to reduce the viscosity of an extract from a plant seed

Tags: biochemistry

I extracted a sample from a plant seed using PBS buffer. The extracted sample is very viscous, even after centrifugation at 15000 rpm for 30 min. The sample is like a thick mucus so that it becomes difficult to do a hemagglutination  assay, and it keeps falling off the pipette tip because of its slimy nature. I can't even estimate the protein content accurately. What can I do to reduce its viscosity?